# Update reactive object made from prop after prop changes

Tags: vue.js

I have the following component:

```
<template>
 <vote-buttons :score="commentRef.score"
               @update-score="updateScore">
 </vote-buttons>
</template>

<script>
 props: {
  comment: {type: Object}
 },
 setup(props) {
  const commentRef = ref(props.comment);
  const updateScore = (value) => {
   commentRef.value.score = value;
  }
 }
</script>
```

Problem is when parent component loops again..

```
<comment v-for="comment in comments" :comment="comment">
</comment>
```

then prop has new data, but `commentRef` is not updated. How to retrigger reactive object creation after prop changes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in the code:

**you should add a key in the parent component:** (Here guessing you have an unique id in comment object)

```
<Comment 
v-for="comment in comments" 
:comment="comment" 
:key="comment.id"></Comment>
```

Define comments as a reactive object, child no need to ref for the props, below give a similar sample but not exactly the same with your code:

**Parent component:**

```
<template>
  <Comment v-for="comment in comments" :comment="comment" :key="comment.id"></Comment>
  <button @click="addCmt">addCmt</button>
</template>

<script>
import Comment from "./components/Comment";
import {reactive} from "vue";
export default {
  name: "Params",
  setup() {
    const comments = reactive([{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 6, name: 'c'}]);
    function addCmt() {
      comments.unshift({id: comments.length + 10, name: 'k'});
    }
    return {
      comments,
      addCmt
    }
  },
  components: {Comment}
}
</script>
```

**Comment component:**

```
<template>
  <div>comments {{ comment.id }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Comment",
  props: ['comment'],
  setup(props, ctx) {
    const comment = props.comment;
    return {comment};
  }
}
</script>
```